# Is there way to get variable names in a scope runtime in java 11?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop

I want to get a map of multiple variables as key-value pairs as in the example. so this method must be genric. Based on the DB configuration string value (keyValuePairTakenFromDB) I need to pick variables and add them to the map.

So my approach was this, get all variables in the current scope and get the variable by its name. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

```
            public void testService() {
                String keyValuePairTakenFromDB = "{\"varName\":\"fileDTO\"}";
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                FileDTO fileDTO = new FileDTO();
                fileDTO.setToken("token12345");
                try {
                    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(keyValuePairTakenFromDB);
                    String variableKey = jsonNode.get("varName").asText();
                    System.out.println("===> " + variableKey);
                    //variableKey=fileDTO
                    HashMap<String, Object> request = new HashMap<>();
                    request.put(variableKey, "get fileDTO object by variableKey");
                    //expected map => request.put(variableKey, fileDTO);
        
                    System.out.println("");
        
                } catch (JsonProcessingException jsonProcessingException) {
                    jsonProcessingException.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you have the slightest interest in stability and security, you do *not* want an external file access arbitrary variables of your program in an uncontrollable way. Even your simple example does already have six local variables in scope, but only one of them is actually intended to be potentially added to the map.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want to add some different values to the map at runtime. Could you mention to me, a way of doing that if this approach is not good.

Comment: Be explicit about the keys and values you want to support. E.g., fill a map with supported keys and their values beforehand, followed by a map lookup. Or use a `switch` statement over the key. With the latest Java versions, you can use a `switch` expression, which is quite concise: `request.put(variableKey, switch(variableKey) { case "fileDTO" -> fileDTO; /* other keys */; default -> throw new ApplicationSpecificException("illegal request"); });` The boilerplate for adding a supported variable would be “`case "name" -> name;`” which is fair considering gained the safety and efficiency.

Comment: This function needs to be used in different services (which contain lots of variables and they can vary). So the switch is kind of not usable for this. I have to add a new case every time when introducing a new variable for any service.

Comment: When you already spent the time and resources to declare and initialize all those variables, whatever you try then won’t give you back what you’ve already wasted.